# Use recursion to solve the position index in a sequence in a C Program?

Tags: c, function, recursion

So there is a sequence of integers, {1, 2, 3, … } , the pattern of this sequence is that  = −1 + ( − 1) and 1 = 1. So if the first five elements in the sequence are: {1 = 1, 2 = 1 + 1 = 2, 3 = 2 + 2 = 4, 4 = 4 + 3 = 7, 5 = 7 + 4 = 11 … } . I am trying to write a program in C to ask the user to input an integer (*an*) to be the position index for this sequence and calculate the value of that position in the sequence. Like the user inputs 7 and it prints that the answer is 22? I have to use recursion and honestly don't even know where to go from that...

I think I am figuring it out, but I am pretty sure this is how it should work and yet it is off by exactly 1!

```
#include <stdio.h>
int sum(int n);

int main()
{
  int number, result;

  printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
  scanf("%d", &number);

  result = sum(number);

  printf("sum=%d", result);
}

int sum(int num)
{
  if (num!=0)
    return num-1 + sum(num-1); // sum() function calls itself
  else
    return num;
}
```

Comment: like [this](https://ideone.com/HWzb7L)

Comment: Check for 1, not for 0.

Comment: @ThreatLevelMidnight__ Your recursion termination condition is incorrect.

Comment: [another version](https://ideone.com/nyJ0tx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I give you a function that magically calculates `a(n-1)`, you can easily calculate `a(n)` right?

```
int a(int n)
{
    int previousA /*a(n-1)*/ = magic(); // magic() knows by itself which n to use
    return previousA + n - 1;
}
```

What if I tell you that `magic()` is exactly the same as `a(n-1)`?

```
int a(int n)
{
    int previousA /*a(n-1)*/ = a(n-1);
    return previousA + n - 1;
}
```

Now, the only problem is that this kind of calling we would get an endless loop of calling - for `a(3)`, `a(2)` is going to be called, then `a(1)`, `a(0)`, `a(-1)`... It'll never end.

What do we do?

Happily, we have an ending condition - `a(1)` is constant and equal to 1.

How do we insert it into the code? We insert a condition to check if `n` is 1, and if it is we simply return, with no further calls.

```
int a(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        int previousA /*a(n-1)*/ = a(n-1);        
        return previousA + n - 1;
    }
}
```

Or in short:

```
int a(int n)
{
    return n == 1 ? a(n - 1) + n - 1 : 1;
}
```

(The `?` and `:` are the syntax for a ternary operator. Read about it if you didn't understand them.)

Comment: Thank you, this actually made some sort of sense.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the name `sum` is not suitable because nothing is summarized. Maybe the function could be named like for example `recursive_sequence`.

The sequence is calculated for non-negative numbers. You have the base condition `a[1] == 1` and the recursive condition `a[n] = a[n-1] + ( n - 1 )`. You should determine the value for the index equal to 0.

You have according to the conditions

```
a[1] == a[0] + ( 1 - 1 )
```

that is

```
a[1] == a[0] + 0
```

so a[0] is equal to 1.

Having this base condition for the index 0 you can write the function

```
unsigned int recursive_sequence(unsigned int n)
{
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n - 1 + recursive_sequence(n - 1);
}
```

Pay attention to that the return type and the type of the parameter should be unsigned integer type.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int recursive_sequence(unsigned int n)
{
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n - 1 + recursive_sequence(n - 1);
}

int main( void )
{
    const unsigned int N = 6;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("%u: %u\n", i, recursive_sequence(i));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
0: 1
1: 1
2: 2
3: 4
4: 7
5: 11
```